# Getting Unchecked runtime.lastError on chrome whenever moving the mouse

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, mouse, runtime-error

I've noticed that I get the following error on Chrome now (not yet sure whether it happens on other browsers):

Whenever I move the mouse, it logs this error in the `console`: `Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.`

This error accumulates whenever the mouse moves in the browser window. i.e. if the mouse is in the console area, it does **not** log the error, similarly, if the mouse is in the bookmarks bar, it does **not** log the error. The error is only logged if the mouse is anywhere on any web page. Check out the image below for the error.

[image: Gif image of the error]

Any idea what I can do about this?

I should note that when I opened Chrome's JavaScript Console today, it gave me the "What's New" message.

***Other info about my PC:***

Google Chrome is up to date `Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Windows 10 Home (64-bit), also up to date

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the problem is with an installed extension not correctly interfacing
with the JavaScript part of the displayed page.

A similar problem is
[well documented](https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill/issues/130)
(although for Firefox), where it is explained with an example.

Try to use Chrome in Incognito mode, where extensions are disabled,
to see if that's indeed the problem, and in that case disable extensions in
normal mode via `chrome://extensions/` until you find the one causing the problem.

Comment: Went through each of my extensions and disabled each in turn to find the offending extension and, unfortunately, it seems to the `StayFocusd` extension - after disabling it, the errors stop. Thanks @harrymc - This solved my issue :)

Comment: In my case it was the MeddleMonkey extension. Removed and replaced with TamperMonkey. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was with the Foxit PDF creator extension in chrome. By disabling this extension (and reloading the page) the error stopped happening.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error by removing Norton Google Chrome extension